# Skip part of youtube video during playback

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to skip parts of a youtube video during playback?

For example:

Play `0s - 15s` then skip to `30s - 60s` then skip to `90s - end`

Answer (score 0):

Use `player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void` to seek to a specified time in the video. [Playback controls and player settings](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) lets you specify the number of seconds that should be skipped before starting to play the video.

There's also simple way as given in [Embed a Part of a YouTube video](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/10/embed-part-of-youtube-video.html).